# Woocommerce How to display Product attributes with shortcode?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, woocommerce, shortcode

I want to display Woocommerce product attributes with a shortcode.

It can look like standard theme style (picture in link below) but a want the shortcode to display what i put in the "Attribute" tab in Product editor.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ql0Dk.png

I need a piece of code to put in my functions.php that creates a shortcode that displays product attributes. Can somebody help?

Answer (score 1):

Using the global $product variable that shows the current product. You can get the attributes from:

```
$product->get_attributes();
```

Then you could simply use a foreach loop, and display them in a table.
Like

```
<table>
<?php 
  foreach($product->get_attributes() as $attribute) {
    ?>
    <tr>
       <td>Attribute name</td> <td>Attribute value</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
  }
?>
</table>
```

Then you can use a plugin like:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-php-code-snippet/
To transform that code into a shortcut.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer @christian. Unfotionally it did not work. There were a server error in elementor. Could you maybe provide me with a code i can put in my functions.php file to create the shortcode?